# Javascript while loop count higher than expected

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a function which takes in a positive number and returns the number of times you must multiply the digits in num until you reach a single digit.

example:

```
test(39) === 3 // because 3*9 = 27, 2*7 = 14, 1*4=4
                   // and 4 has only one digit//if single digit return num
```

The code:

```
function test(num) {
if (num > 10) { return num} else {
   var j = num;var a;var count = 0;
while ( j > 10){
   a = num.toString().split('').map( e=> parseInt(e)).reduce((a,c)=> a*c);
   num = a;
   count++;
   j--; 
   }  
return count;
}}

test(39) //outputs 29 expected 3;
```

I have fixed the above by adding an array and filtering for unique values but would still like to know why the code is giving me a much higher count than expected.

Comment: If `num` is already below 10, shouldn't it return `0` and not the number itself? I mean you describe your function as returning the number of iterations, not a result from a calculation.

Comment: The `j--` part is the bit that's making the result far too high.  You can add `console.log(a,num,j)` inside the while to see what it's doing (or step through with the debugger).  Also `return num` at the start makes no sense, should be `return 0` as num<10 means it's already single digit so doesn't need to run your algorithm.

Comment: You're right,dunno why i even put that j part and forgot about it.Works without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking to use *recursion* here - if the `num` is smaller than `10`, return 0, otherwise, perform the needed multiplication, and then return `1 +` *the result of calling `test` on the product*:

```js
function test(num) {
  return num < 10
  ? 0
  : 1 + test(
    num.toString().split('').reduce((a, c) => a * c)
  )
}

console.log(test(39));
```

(note that `*` will coerce strings to numbers already, no need for `parseInt`)

Comment: What happened to `if (num < 10)` **`{ return num }`**?

Comment: `return num` doesn't make sense if OP is trying to figure out the *number of iterations* required to produce a single digit number

Comment: @PeterB that's handled with the `?:` = `if (num<10) return 0;`

Comment: True, description by OP does not seem to match what they tried.

Comment: Thanks guys.This works.Also the > sign in the first line was a type,now corrected

Answer (score 1):

Correction in your code, you can compare

```
    function test(num) {
if (num < 10) { return num} else {
   var a;var count = 0;
while ( num > 10){
   a = num.toString().split('').map( e=> parseInt(e)).reduce((a,c)=> a*c);
   num = a;
   count++;

   }  
return count;
}}

test(39) //outputs 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're decrementing j, which is initially 39. It will reach 10, then it will return the number of times it was decremented (29 times, which coincides with your result). You need to do the following, assuming the split part is correct:

```
function test(num) {
if (num < 10) { return num} else {
   var j = num;var a = 11; // just to enter the while loop at least once
   var count = 0;
while ( a > 10){
   a = num.toString().split('').map( e=> parseInt(e)).reduce((a,c)=> a*c);
   num = a;
   count++;
   j--; 
   }  
return count;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You decremented your `num` by 1 each iteration. It gives you `29` because `39 - 10` is `29`. You didn't update the actual `num` which you need to compare if it's still greater than 10.

Do this instead:

```js
function test(num) {
  if (num < 10) {
    return num
  } else {
    var count = 0;
    while (num > 10) {
      num = num.toString().split('').map(e => parseInt(e)).reduce((a, c) => a * c);
      count++;
    }
    return count;
  }
}

console.log(test(39))
```